# For Each loop on selected Arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, named-ranges

This for each loop will check out all the named range in my active sheet and do something.

```
Sub Test1
For Each namedRanges In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If namedRanges.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then MsgBox namedRanges.Name
Next namedRanges
End Sub
```

however, I just want to call a certain Names for them to do something and they are static. How do I do that?

I tried declaring the Named ranges I want but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
Sub Test3()
Dim nameArr(1 To 3) As Integer
Dim vari As Variant
nameArr("Page1") = 1: nameArr("Page2") = 2: nameArr("Page3") = 3
Dim idx As Long
    For idx = LBound(nameArr) To UBound(nameArr)
        vari = nameArr(idx)
        MsgBox vari
    Next idx
End Sub
```

I made a variable nameArr as my static array here with the purpose for them to be the only one to do something within the for each loop.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It’s not clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop Over a List of Names

```vb
Sub LoopNames()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Loop Over a List of Names"
    
    Dim SelectedNames As Variant:
    SelectedNames = Array("Page1", "Page2", "Page3")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim nm As Name, rg As Range, SelectedName As Variant, IsNameRange As Boolean
    
    For Each SelectedName In SelectedNames
        
        ' Attempt to reference the name.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set nm = wb.Names(SelectedName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If nm Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The name """ & SelectedName & """ doesn't exist!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            ' Attempt to reference the range.
            On Error Resume Next
                Set rg = nm.RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rg Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "The existing name """ & nm.Name _
                    & """ doesn't refer to a range!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Else
                IsNameRange = True ' the name refers to a range
            End If
        End If
        
        If IsNameRange Then
           ' Do something with the range or the name or 'their' worksheet, e.g.:
            MsgBox "Sheet: " & vbTab & rg.Worksheet.Name & vbLf _
                & "Name: " & vbTab & nm.Name & vbLf _
                & "Range: " & vbTab & rg.Address(0, 0), _
                vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
           
           ' Your code for each name (range, worksheet)...
        
        End If
        
        ' Reset for the next iteration.
        IsNameRange = False
        Set rg = Nothing
        Set nm = Nothing
    
    Next SelectedName
    
    MsgBox "List of names processed: " & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(SelectedNames, vbLf), vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim nameArr, vari, refRange As Range
    Dim idx As Long, oName As Name
    ' Name range list
    nameArr = Array("Page1", "Page2", "Page3")
    For idx = LBound(nameArr) To UBound(nameArr)
        ' Get the named range, the return is a Name object or nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oName = ThisWorkbook.Names(nameArr(idx))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If oName Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print nameArr(idx) & " does not exist"
        Else
            ' Get the RefersToRange, the return is a Range object or nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set refRange = oName.RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not refRange Is Nothing Then
                ' check name's scope
                If refRange.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
                    Debug.Print nameArr(idx) & " refer to " & refRange.Address(0, 0)
                End If
                Set refRange = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        Set oName = Nothing
    Next idx
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Array function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [UBound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)